# "Unfortunately App has stopped" after running 'expo eject'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, workflow

I have a app that was working in the managed workflow. I ran

```
expo eject
```

To get my app to the bare workflow
After everything was good I ran

```
yarn android
```

To run my app on a real device connected through usb and as soon as the app opens I get

```
Unfornately, ______ has stopped
```

---

USB debugging is on in my developer options

These are some packages I import if thats of any help, I get the sense it is

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack'
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs'
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'
import * as RNIap from 'react-native-iap';


import { AdMobBanner } from 'expo-ads-admob'
import * as InAppPurchases from 'expo-in-app-purchases';
import * as Sharing from 'expo-sharing'; // Import the library
import { Audio } from 'expo-av'
```

---

Solutions which did not help

```
yarn cache clean --force
```

Comment: You could try connecting the device to your computer and running `adb logcat *:E` while opening the app to see errors logged from the device. One of the errors should mention why the app is crashing.

Comment: @StanisławChmiela `zsh: no matches found: *:E`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have no idea how `adb logcat *:E`(mentioned by Stanislaw) is supposed to work, but I was able to view a panel called logcat when I opened up Android Studio. I have been using Visual Studio, so android studio was closed before.

[image]

The logcat panel told me I had an error which had something to do with admob. I can't remember what it is because it was overwritten when I got my app working.

---

I had to insert this line into my AndroidManifest.xml file inside `<application`

```
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-1111111111~11111111111"/>
```

But replace all the ones with your admob ad-unit-id that you get from admob when creating an ad unit

Comment: In general it works like the _Logcat_ tab in Android Studio (`*:E` filters only errors). I'm glad you sorted this out using Android Studio (it's a much better debugging experience than in the terminal, but it also requires a project set up). 

Comment: @StanisławChmiela What do you mean by project setup? Once my app was in the bare workflow, there was a folder named android inside my main folder, which I was able to open in android studio. I was then able to run my app with the command line and see the errors under `Logcat` in Android Studio

Comment: It is not strictly common for React Native developers to have Java installed, feel comfortable opening Android Studio, etc. `adb logcat` felt like a more straightforward way to achieve the goal.